# NullPointerException formatMissingContructorExceptionMessage in JpaRepository while server start up

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are using JpaRepository and defined customized SELECT query with alias column name but while server start up getting java.lang.NullPointerException at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.formatMissingContructorExceptionMessage(ConstructorNode.java:192)

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RevenueRepository extends JpaRepository<Revenue, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new net.models.CategoryRevenue(cr.category, date_part('month',cr.fileDate) AS tx_month, TO_CHAR(cr.fileDate,'YYYY') AS tx_year, sum(cr.varianceRevenueMismatch) AS revenue) from Revenue cr where cr.category = 'ERROR' and cr.shadow = false and cr.fileDate > '2022-01-01' and cr.fileDate < '2022-07-01' group by cr.category,tx_month,tx_year order by date_part('month',cr.fileDate) ASC")
    public List<CategoryRevenue> findRevenue();
}
```

Class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class CategoryRevenue {
    private String category;
    private double tx_month;
    private String tx_year;
    private int revenue;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "comparator_revenue")
public class Revenue {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;
    @Column(name = "category_type")
    private String categoryType;
    @Column(name = "total_count")
    private Integer totalCount;
    @Column(name = "ath_revenue_mismatch")
    private Integer athRevenueMismatch;
    @Column(name = "afls_revenue_mismatch")
    private Integer aflsRevenueMismatch;
    @Column(name = "variance_revenue_mismatch")
    private Integer varianceRevenueMismatch;
    @Column(name = "file_name")
    private String fileName;
    @Column(name = "file_date")
    private LocalDate fileDate;
    @Column(name = "updated_time_stamp")
    private Timestamp updatedTimeStamp;
    @Column(name = "shadow")
    private Boolean shadow;
    @Column(name = "pipeline")
    private String pipeline;

}
```

Exception Details:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.formatMissingContructorExceptionMessage(ConstructorNode.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.resolveConstructor(ConstructorNode.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.ConstructorNode.prepare(ConstructorNode.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processConstructor(HqlSqlWalker.java:1258)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2395)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1523)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:330)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 88 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49670', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[Click here to see Table's data and it's type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DUQZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that none of the constructors in the class
you are using match the signature you are using in the select clause.

I don't know which db you are using,but I expect `date_part('month',cr.fileDate) AS tx_month` to return a number between 1 and 12 that's going to be converted to an `Integer`, and not a `double` like you've defined in your class.

I suspect that's the issue. But, it could also be another field or maybe Lombok didn't generate the parameters in the right order.

You can debug it declaring all fields as object and adding a breakpoint in the constructor to check the type of the passed parameters.

Comment: The date_part() function is used to return the part of a date and time. Return Type: double precision, that's why tx_month is double

Comment: Which db are you using? Anyway, the error is because there’s no constructor matching those parameters.

Comment: It can only be that one of the types is wrong, or Lombok generated it with something wrong.

Comment: the `date_part` function will return a number between 1 and 12 and hibernate is going to convert it to an integer.

Comment: I am using postgreql . Instead of date_part function I used TO_CHAR function which gives character_varying datatype and mapped with String at Java side & for bigInt at postgesql , used Long at Java side which solves the problem. Thank you